# Swift hour and minute from a string to a Date

Tags: swift, string, date, type-conversion

I'm trying to apply some calcul between two hours.

I receive from firebase my too hours from a String format (HH:mm) and I try to convert it to a Date format (HH:mm). Then apply the calcul before converting again to a string and seed it to the archive in Firebase.

My code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

ref.child("Experience").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot) in
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:String]{
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let total_time = value?["TOTAL_TIME"] as? String ?? "00:00" // Received from Firebase

        self.oldDateTotalTime = dateFormatter.date(from: total_time)! //trying to convert into a Date format
        print(self.oldDateTotalTime)

        self.oldStringTotalTime = total_time //just for test
    }
```

This code didn't work because, I think, of the `dateFormatter`.

S my questions are:

1. How can I get my `Date` from my `String`?
2. How can I get after my `String` from my `Date`?

**edit:**
to precise my question, my objective is to subtract one time value to a total time value. I've got a total user experience i.e 700 H 50 min with is given on Firebase like this : 700:50. In an other part I've got some specific experiences i.e 1h 40min with is given as before 1:40 in firebase.
My request is to subtract the specific experience from the global.

```
700:50 - 1:40 = 699:10
```

On my current Swift experience I only use `Date()` & `DateFormatter` to deal with the time and I don't know how to deal only with time and not with date ...

Hope you will better understand this with my edit

Comment: What is your goal here? What does it mean to you to convert a string such as "14:30" into a `Date`? What day, month, and year do you expect? Why are you trying to convert a time string into a date?

Comment: What calculation are you referring to? The code you posted only attempts to work with a single time string. Please [edit] your question and fully clarify what you are trying to do and what issues you are having. Do not reply with comments.

Comment: What you mean by `didn't work`? Are there any errors being thrown? What's the behavior you're getting?

Comment: For time calculations without date information `DateComponents` is preferable

Comment: I've got edited my request I hope this will be most easier to understand for you !

Comment: @FLyer74 if you get results as 700:50, I would parse the string with a simple regex to get the number of hours and minutes. Subtract hours to get deltaHours, subtract minutes to get deltaMinutes; if deltaMinutes are negative, subtract 1 from deltaHours and add 60 to deltaMinutes.

Comment: You should change how you are doing this. Don’t save these values as strings. Save these values as integers representing minutes. Do your calculations with the integers. Only deal with a string when you wish to present the number of minutes to the user. Then format the integer ad needed into a string.

Comment: I've put a String because I present the result to the user ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need, here is the regex code ; can certainly be optimised.

```
func stringToTime(_ timeStr: String) -> (Int, Int) {
    var hours = 0
    var minutes = 0
    let patternH = "[0-9]*[:]" // digits, followed by :
    let regexH = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: patternH, options: .caseInsensitive)
    if let matchH = regexH.firstMatch(in: timeStr, range: NSRange(0..<timeStr.utf16.count)) {
        let hStr = String(timeStr[Range(matchH.range(at: 0), in: timeStr)!]).dropLast()
        hours = Int(hStr) ?? 0
        let patternM = "[:][0-9]{1,2}"  //  1 or 2 digits
        let regexM = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: patternM, options: .caseInsensitive)
        if let matchM = regexM.firstMatch(in: timeStr, range: NSRange(0..<timeStr.utf16.count)) {
            let mStr = String(timeStr[Range(matchM.range(at: 0), in: timeStr)!]).dropFirst()
            minutes = Int(mStr) ?? 0
        }
    }

    return (hours, minutes)
}

let timeStr = "700:50"
let time1 = stringToTime("700:50")
let time2 = stringToTime("1:40")

var time = (time1.0 - time2.0, time1.1 - time2.1)
if time.1 < 0 {
    time.1 = time.1 + 60
    time.0 -= 1
}

print(time)
```

Comment: This work totally as I want ! The result `time` is now 699, 10 but how can I get back into a string with this format : 699:10 ?

Comment: ok I just understand how to get my format like 699:10 I did : `String = "\(time.0):\(time.1)"` and this give me my string with my format ! Thanks a lot !